# PhoneGap build API PUT with .NET HttpClient or WebRequest

Tags: c#, phonegap-build

How can I simulate following with `HttpClient` or `WebRequest`?

> curl -d "data={\"keys\":{\"android\":
>   {\"id\":1111,\"key_pw\":\"pass1\",\"keystore_pw\":\"pass2\"}}}" -X PUT
>   https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps/1111?auth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX

I am getting `404 Not Found` with `HttpClient`.

```
 var url = "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps/00000/build?auth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 var obj = new { keys = new { android = new { id = 111, key_pw = "xxx", keystore_pw = "xxx" } } };
 var client = new HttpClient();
 var resp = client.PutAsJsonAsync(url, obj);
 var res = resp.Result; //404
```

Comment: posted c# code as requested

Comment: You do realize that the URL's are different between the curl and c# code right?

Comment: what do you mean? that I replaced appId with 1111 in one case and 00000 in another?